# Force stop in android

Tags: android

What is the `Force stop` in `setting` and in the part of the Manage Applications in the android? I ask this question because even we create a simple program for android and when we launch it and then when we close the program using the backward button and then when we go to the `the Manage Applications` in the setting, the `Force stop` is enable for the program still. Is this event good? what is this really?

Comment: Force stop -- hmm not 100% sure but  it will stop all the processes of that app running in the background -- someone asked this Q allready here -- http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33801/what-does-the-force-stop-button-mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally pressing back button doesn't fully stop an application. It stops its UI part (i.e. finishes activities, etc.). But some applications may still have some background services running, alarms scheduled, broadcast receivers registered, etc. Force stop button makes sure **everything** is stopped, so all those parts will not be run until you manually launch your app again